# How to run android macros from a remote computer by command line?

Tags: android, testing, macros, network-traffic

I need a mechanism, or software, or platform (I don't know what would be my solution) to run some routine (something like macros) in Android environment from command line, remotely (PC).

**Example:** A macro that runs an app and clicks some buttons in that app and this action started from a remote computer via a CLI command.

**The following requirements should also be meet:**

- My desired macros should be able to run apps, click button, swipe, etc.;
- The script for generating macro should be simple (or the better, macro recorded automatically);
- Most importantly, it should be run remotely (e.g.: it enables me to run the macro from another computer (command line) in Android emulator.

**what I have found:**

- Something such as Automated UI test tools maybe useful!
- Android Espresso;
- Xamarin automatic test in Visual Studio.

But, what I really need is not UI testing tools, I need such thing in order to capture application traffic periodically with that macro.

Moreover, my solution maybe combination of tools and suggestions.

Comment: Hi Kevin, and welcome to SO! Unfortunately, this question is not really suitable for SO, as. Have a look at the [help/on-topic] for guidance on what is on-topic here.